# PhoneGap: How do I get appView's id and pass it around?

Tags: android, cordova, webview

For PhoneGap Application, as the instruction said, I have replaced the `setContentView()` line with `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");` and the next line is `appView.addJavascriptInterface( new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");`

My question is

1. if I wanna use appView in my JSInterface, how can I find it, or pass it into JSInterface, or reference it from JSInterface.
2. And is appView the only webview in PhoneGap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should not take the approach of adding your own JS interface. It is better if you write a PhoneGap plugin:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android

We've already suffered through all the pains of making sure the JS interfaces are setup correctly. From your plugin you can get access to appView by using:

```
this.webView
```

Yes, appView is the only webview in PhoneGap.