# How can I call native functions in Phonegap through Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am developing an application for Android using PhoneGap. I have implemented some of the functions in Java. How can I call those Java functions using Javascript?

Comment: Is your java code deployed on the android with the application or is it deployed on a remote server?

Answer (score 4):

there is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8733773/905565

Write [your own plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android), or provide JavaScript interface with [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) method of WebView

Access to webview in your phonegap activity with `this.webView`