# How to use android native code in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an android application using phonegap and i came across some things which are quite easy to implement in android native code when compare to phonegap. So i want to know is there any way in which i can make use of android code by not changing my phonegap cross platform?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar question: [How can I call native functions in Phonegap through Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609326/how-can-i-call-native-functions-in-phonegap-through-javascript/11610435#11610435)

You can write phonegap plugin

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html