# Run native code in Phonegap (Java Android)

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I need to generate pulses to create a frequency from my android device (to communicate to arduino via the audio jack, but this is not important).
 Natively, java allows us to do that as explained [here](http://ultimoistante.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/android-e-arduino-simple-audio-communication-part1/).
Unfortunately this is impossible to do via javascript, so I need to run this native code in my app through Javascript.
I'm a complete ignorant about "running Java from JS", so, can you suggest me a tutorial where to learn from, or help me somehow?

Comment: Take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609326/how-can-i-call-native-functions-in-phonegap-through-javascript/11610435#11610435](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609326/how-can-i-call-native-functions-in-phonegap-through-javascript/11610435#11610435)

Answer (score 2):

You need to write an Android plugin for this, [Phonegap Android Plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins) is the phonegap API documentation for writing a plugin. You need to call your Android Plugin through JavaScript.

Here is a [Sample PhoneGap plugin for Android](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-how-to-write-a-phonegap-plugin-for-android/)