# Android Gallery not showing images stored from app

Tags: android, cordova, gallery

I'm doing a phoneGap app, which makes some changes to a pic and save it back to the //sdcard/Download/ folder. Using third-party app like ES File Explorer, I can see the pic added to the Download folder. However, the Galley does not seem to acknowledge the change even after I hit the refresh button. Any thoughts?

```
function copyPic(){
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imagefilename, resOnSuccess, fail);
```

}

function resOnSuccess(entry){

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function(fileSys) {
            fileSys.root.getDirectory("Download", {create:false, exclusive: false},
                function(directory) {
                    entry.copyTo(directory, "newFile1.JPG", success, fail);
                }, fail);
        }, fail);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

will update your gallery, but it takes some time.

Comment: Thanks xtr. I'm using phoneGap, so wondering if there exists similar methods there?

Comment: Write your own plugin, or provide JavaScript interface with addJavascriptInterface method of WebView to call that native function. You can see detail in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733692/phonegap-how-do-i-get-appviews-id-and-pass-it-around/8733773